How to get Modulation removed CW signal from Pi/2 BPSK modulated signal?
I am doing Coarse Frequency offset estimation for DVB-S2. But I'm having problem like how should I get the ck from 90 symbols pi/2 BPSK modulated received signal. I'm wondering can I use Mth power method.


You know what the pilot sequence is, correct? In that case you should be able to remove the modulation directly (since you know it)

The Problem I'm facing is that I know a little part of the PL header which is SOF 26 Symbols. The other 64 symbols are PLS code which are encoded and scrambled. so here I'm confused.

@DanBoschen PLHEADER is actually a data-containing header, BUT: it's always preceded by a 26 symbol known "symbols start-of-frame". Also, PLSCODE carries 7 bit of information in 64 bits. (and it's structured sync-friendly: it's 6 bits of information channel-coded into 32 bits, then you repeat each bit, so that it's now 64 bits. While copying, you invert the bit if the 7. info bit was 1. Afterwards, put through QPSK mapping, if I'm not mistaken. So, I and Q are always the same in the resulting symbol stream (so, either $1+1j$ or $-1-1j$) or they are always opposite (so $1-1j$ or $-1+1j$); hence

phase recovery on the 64 symbols of PLSCODE within PLHEADER is simply a BPSK recovery problem, which is rather manageable at typical SNRs. If the SNR is really bad, one could try to throw a 2⁶-wide, 2⁵ deep correlator bank at the problem, but I'm not sure in a regime where that would seem appropriate that any of the rest of the system would operate well enough.

@MarcusMüller I'm currently raising my signal to 4th power to get modulation removed CW singal. is it correct ?

@MuhammadUmar that is certainly a textbook way, yes that works! It, however, comes with significant amplification of noise, so your performance might be worse at the worse ends of still-receivable SNR. But for starters: go with it, sounds good enough if you have a good signal, and if it's not good enough for all signals you want to deal with, replace it later with something control-loopy.

Ok. for something control-loopy like FLL, I must know the modulation scheme at which data is coming and here I'm only using the PL header which is PI/2 BPSK for coarse estimation in that I have 26 symbols known. This would be an easier task If I have 90 symbols known I guess.

wasn't thinking of an FLL, but more of a Costas loop on the PLHEADER, for which you do know the modulation scheme. But for an FLL, you don't need to know the constellation at all – knowing the pulse shape suffices, and IIRC, that's the same for all of DVB-S2?
